# onPostExecute is called only one time

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have a problem when I execute my AsyncTask: the method onPostExecute() is only execute one time. The second time there is no update.

Log:

```
05-31 23:15:35.261 31682-32136/com.stimulus D/result45: Qu'est ce que c'est ?
05-31 23:15:35.301 31682-31682/com.stimulus D/result50: Qu'est ce que c'est ?
05-31 23:15:38.201 31682-31878/com.stimulus D/result45: C'est quoi ?
05-31 23:15:38.261 31682-31682/com.stimulus D/result50: Qu'est ce que c'est ?
```

Code:

```
class NextQuestionChooseAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(QuestionActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream is = null;


            email = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("email");
            password = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("password");
            idSession = (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("idSession");
            String json = null;
            String result = null;
            String question = null;

            try {
                //Http request to communicate with our system
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters = new LinkedList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idsession", String.valueOf(idSession)));


                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
                URI website = new URI("http://192.168.1.33:5001/nextquestion" + "?"+ URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "utf-8"));
                httpGet.setURI(website);

                String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(
                        (email + ":" + password).getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);

                Log.d("test",base64EncodedCredentials);

                httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();

                Log.d("result1", result);

                //Manage JSON result
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                question = jsonObject.getString("question");

                Log.d("result45",question);

                questionInformation.add(question);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return questionInformation;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> status) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            String question = questionInformation.get(0);

            Log.d("result50",question);
            tv_title_question.setText(question);

        }
    }
    NextQuestionChooseAsync nqca = new NextQuestionChooseAsync();
    nqca.execute();
}
```

Why the second time the value question in method onPostExecute() doesn't change?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What do you mean by second time?  An AsyncTask can only be run once.  Executing the same task again is an error.

Comment: The AsyncTask is called when I click on a button. The first time the value question in method onPostExecute() is equal to the value adding in the list in doBackground but the second time no ...

Comment: Where is questionInformation declared?  Outside the AsyncTask?  If so that's a problem-  you're likely running into race conditions.  And even if not that's the problem-  you're adding to that list, so the second time the value you aded would be in position 1, not 0.  But really you just shouldn't be declaring that value outside of the AsyncTask, and if you need to you should be adding to it in onPostExecute, not in doInBackground

Comment: Thanks :) it's because questionInformation was declared outside the AsyncTask.